Slickslider: different navigation and slides ordering
Slickslider has the feature of "Slider Syncing", or navigation, where there are two sliders, one beeing a navigation, and another the slides themselves. Clicking a navigation item sets the corresponding slide item as active/current slide.
Default behaviour makes a one to one association between navigation items and slides items by order, i.e., the first navigation item corresponds to the first slide item, the second navigation item corresponds to the secong slide item, and so on.
My question is: is it possible to customize this correspondence?
To give a concrete example, a have a slider where each slide is one year, and I want to navigate only through decades. So, in this examples, for 30 slides (1990 to 2019), I want only 3 navigation items (1990, 2000, 2010), each one pointing to the first year of each decade.
best,
alan
